# Fast way to compute the determinant of all minors (and minors of minors)

Tags: matlab, indexing, linear-algebra, determinants

I have an invertible Hermitian matrix [image: M\in \mathbb{C}^{K\times K}] and [image: 2^K] square submatrices of [image: M], [image: ${M_S}_{S\subseteq {1,\dots,K}}$] defined:

[image: \begin{equation}M_S = (\text{submatrix consisting only of rows and columns $S$ from $M$}) \in \mathbb{C}^{|S|\times |S|}\end{equation}]

I need to know the determinant of every [image: $M_S$].

Is there a fast way of computing this in MATLAB?

---

Here is the bad way to do it:

- Loop over `[1:2^K]`
- Convert loop index to binary vector `vSubset`
- Compute `det(mtxM(vSubset,vSubset))`

This runs slow and seems wasteful, since you can build the determinant of a parent matrix from the determinant of its minors.

Comment: K is order ~3-7, but the entire thing must be run potentially hundreds of thousands of times.

Comment: For a general matrix this requires running Laplace's formula recursively. So it will take O(K!)

Comment: Is your matrix positive definite?

Comment: It is a covariance matrix so yes.

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to use the Cholesky factorisation. I use the upper triangular form below, so that

```
M = U'*U
```

where ' is adjoint and U is upper triangular.
Note that det(M) = square( |det(U)|) and that the determinant of U is the product of its diagonal elements.

We can compute the factor of a matrix obtained from M by appending a row and column like this:

```
M~ = ( M  n )
     ( n' p )
U~ = ( U  x )
     ( 0  y )
```

where

```
U'*x = n 
y = sqrt( p - x'*x)
```

and so det( M~) = det( M) * ( p - x'*x)

I'm not sure of the best way to use this. There is quite a neat recursive way: in pseudo C code

```
void det_step( double* U, double det, int high_ix)
{ 
int ix;
  for( ix=high_ix+1; ix<dim; ++ix)
  { // notionally add row, col ix
    // augment U, update det (and store in the output)
    det_step( U, det, ix);
  }
}
void dets( double* M, int dim)
{
int ix;
   for( ix=0; ix<dim; ++ix)
   { // compute U and det for matrix consisting of just row/col ix
     // store det in the output
     det_step( U, det, ix);
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this together with looping through all the submatrices ordered by size (Gosper's hack) does it.